# SimpleJdbcCall performance

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

Is there a reason for a call to a storedprocedure taking considerably longer while using SimpleJdbcCall compared to using the RowMapper mechanism in spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess did the trick. I can conclude that the performance impact was due to the meta data lookup that was done to get the parameters for the stored proc.

Answer (score 6):

SimpleJDBCCall is multi threaded and should be re-used. Re-use in the sense the same object is to be used to call the same procedure again and again.  the metadata access is done only once.

Even if we use the SimpleJDBCCall withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess. it still interacts with DB to get other metadata information.